# Checking for balanced brackets in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, balanced-delimiters

I'm solving [HackerRank "Stacks: Balanced Brackets"](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-balanced-brackets/problem) in Python.

> A bracket is considered to be any one of the following characters: `(`,
>   `)`, `{`, `}`, `[`, or `]`.
>
> Two brackets are considered to be a matched pair if the an opening
>   bracket (i.e., `(`, `[`, or `{`) occurs to the left of a closing bracket
>   (i.e., `)`, `]`, or `}`) of the exact same type. There are three types of
>   matched pairs of brackets: `[]`, `{}`, and `()`.
>
> A matching pair of brackets is not balanced if the set of brackets it
>   encloses are not matched. For example, `{[(])}` is not balanced because
>   the contents in between `{` and `}` are not balanced. The pair of square
>   brackets encloses a single, unbalanced opening bracket, `(`, and the
>   pair of parentheses encloses a single, unbalanced closing square
>   bracket, `]`.
>
> By this logic, we say a sequence of brackets is considered to be
>   balanced if the following conditions are met:
>
> It contains no unmatched brackets. The subset of brackets enclosed
>   within the confines of a matched pair of brackets is also a matched
>   pair of brackets. Given  strings of brackets, determine whether each
>   sequence of brackets is balanced. If a string is balanced, print `YES`
>   on a new line; otherwise, print `NO` on a new line.

My code:

```
def is_matched(expression):
    if len(expression) % 2 != 0:
        return False

    opening = ("(", "[", "{")
    closing = (")", "]", "}")
    mapping = {opening[0]:closing[0],
               opening[1]:closing[1],
               opening[2]:closing[2]}

    if expression[0] in closing:
        return False

    if expression[-1] in opening:
        return False

    closing_queue = []
    for letter in expression:
        if letter in opening:
            closing_queue.append(mapping[letter])
        elif letter in closing:
            if not closing_queue:
                return False

            if closing_queue[-1] == letter:
                closing_queue.pop()
            else:
                return False

    return True

t = int(input().strip())
for a0 in range(t):
    expression = input().strip()
    if is_matched(expression) == True:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

What could be improved here? What can be done to make my code more idiomatic (pythonic code)?

Is my implementation bad? Why is it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Review

Your implementation is quite good, but ofcourse there are always some things that can be improved upon.

1. Use a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, see what they do.
2. `opening` `closing` and `mapping` could be done a bit simpler

   - You may use `list` over the values, to create a list,
   - And you may `zip` those in a dictionary with the `zip` keyword.
3. If you need to add alot of corner cases, your algorithm is likely off somewhere else.
4. Consider adding *Testcases*, *Docstrings*, or both in the form of *Doctest*. To make it easier to Test your algorithm.

## Alternative code

```
def is_matched(expression):
    """
    Finds out how balanced an expression is.
    With a string containing only brackets.

    >>> is_matched('[]()()(((([])))')
    False
    >>> is_matched('[](){{{[]}}}')
    True
    """
    opening = tuple('({[')
    closing = tuple(')}]')
    mapping = dict(zip(opening, closing))
    queue = []

    for letter in expression:
        if letter in opening:
            queue.append(mapping[letter])
        elif letter in closing:
            if not queue or letter != queue.pop():
                return False
    return not queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: `opening = tuple('({[')` could be `opening = '({['`, and similar for `closing`

Comment: Also consider writing `mapping = dict(('()', '{}', '[]'))`.

Comment: You could also use `mapping = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']'}`, but it's less readable (it is somewhat more efficient).

Comment: @SolomonUcko: There is zero significant difference in performance in the two ways of constructing a constant dict of size `3`. To choose a less readable option because it is "somewhat more efficient" would be preposterous in this case.

Comment: @wchargin I thought it would be slightly faster, as the dict constructor wouldn't have to iterate through the tuple of strings.

Comment: @SolomonUcko: It *is* faster. But the difference is not meaningful; this is an operation that takes microseconds and is performed only once; it is nowhere *close* to the bottleneck. This is *exactly* why people say not to prematurely optimize. *Write good code* and *write readable code*; only *then* should you profile and optimize hot spots.

Comment: @wchargin That makes sense. I was just pointing it out, not actually as a real suggestion.

Comment: Is this function appropriate to check on a whole document, not only a single expression?

Comment: @Sigur Yes it will ignore all other chars in `expression` that are not brackets, so if your `expression` is a really long string it might work

Comment: @Ludisposed If I am not mistaken, since we are appending to the list (adding an element to the tail) then calling pop() on the list giving us the last element, doesn't this make it a stack instead of a queue? IIRC a stack is LIFO and a queue is FIFO

Comment: @Kevin This has been said by another awnser and therefore left it out in this review.

Answer (score 14):

- What if you enter something that isn't a bracket? Currently you ignore that, maybe you would want to error.
- You don't need to make `opening` and `closing`. You can just use `mapping`.

```
def is_matched(expression):
    mapping = dict(zip('({[', ')}]'))
    queue = []
    for letter in expression:
        if letter in mapping:
            queue.append(mapping[letter])
        elif letter not in mapping.values():
            raise ValueError('Unknown letter {letter}'.format(letter=letter))
        elif not (queue and letter == queue.pop()):
            return False
    return not queue
```

---

If however you didn't want to ignore it or error, you could just remove the check, and have the code return `False`:

```
def is_matched(expression):
    mapping = dict(zip('({[', ')}]'))
    queue = []
    for letter in expression:
        if letter in mapping:
            queue.append(mapping[letter])
        elif not (queue and letter == queue.pop()):
            return False
    return not queue
```

Comment: Now I see, what you mean with the `opening` and `closing` being unnecessary. Just iterate over the `mapping`.

Comment: @Ludisposed At first I meant it as you could just use a string. But then noticed you didn't need them at all... :)

Comment: To further add to your answer, `mapping` could be a constant

Answer (score 10):

Another thing to fix is the misleading name of the list variable. Items go in and out in LIFO order, making this a *stack* and not a *queue*.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers have already covered what can be improved in your script so I will not repeat any of that. Just wanted to add an alternative I found interesting.

An *elimination-based* approach:

```
def f(my_string):
    brackets = ['()', '{}', '[]']
    while any(x in my_string for x in brackets):
        for br in brackets:
            my_string = my_string.replace(br, '')
    return not my_string
```

In every iteration the innermost brackets get eliminated (replaced with empty string). If we end up with an empty string, our initial one was balanced; otherwise, not.

---

Examples and notes:

- **Best** case: `s = '[](){}{}()[]'` -> reduces to nothing in one `while` iteration.
- **Worst** case: `s = '({[[{()}]]})'` -> same length string requires 6 iterations (destroyed inside out)

You could add some short-circuiting for quickly catching cases of lengthy strings that have an uneven number of opening and closing brackets so that you don't waste your time eliminating...

Comment: @Cimbali try to write it like that and see if you end up with something simpler and easier to understand than the code above.

Comment: @Cimbali I do not see any

Comment: @Cimbali Nice work. Only the `return` was changed since it was "upside-down"

Answer (score 2):

One of the most frequent remarks on this site also applies here: make sure your code has comments to explain not just what it is doing, but what the reasoning is behind the code the comment is relevant towards.. The next person who needs to maintain your code will thank you for it, and if you ever have to look at your code again in half a year or so, you're going to be thankful you took the effort right now.

Comment: Do you really think that comments are essential? I think the code must be self-explanatory. If it needs lots of comments it's probably bad or redundant.

Comment: @vnbrs The debate between having well documented code and self-explanatory code is one that's been raging ever since programming was invented. The core of the matter is that even if you think your code is self-explanatory for you right now, in 3 years, someone fresh out of school with very little experience who is hired to maintain your code will be very happy to at least have a clue what's going on in your code from the comments. For example, I would very much like to have comments explaining the algorithm in the question. Not explaining the code, but the algorithm the code is implementing.

Comment: While the code may be readable, the comments should explain WHY the code is doing what it is doing, since the reader may not be familiar with the algorithm or corner case.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing these algorithms, and it works well, but in some cases, they will fail. I would treat it as a string, using a stack, because it could works for a compiler, and could be more than parentheses, brackets and keys.

Test these cases, and if it works in all cases, you are doing well:

```
string = "[]{}()[][][]"
print "Should be true"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "([()][][{}])"
print "Should be true"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "[(])"
print "Should be false"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "[([])()({})]"
print "Should be true"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "[(,,),(,,[])]"
print "Should be true but it fails"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "[(,,,(,,[])]"
print "Should be false"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "]"
print "Should be false"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "["
print "Should be false"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "{[{}][][({})]}"
print "Should be true"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = """
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
"""

print "Should be true"
print str(is_matched(string))

string = "[[[((({{{}}})))]]]"
print "Should be true"
print str(is_matched(string))
```

This is my working solution, that works for all cases:

```
def pairs_stack(string, pairs = {'[': ']', '{': '}', '(': ')'}):

    opening = pairs.keys()

    closing = pairs.values()

    match = list()

    for s in string:
        if s in opening:
            match.insert(0, s)
        elif s in closing:
            if len(match) == 0:
                return False
            if match[0] == opening[closing.index(s)]:
                match.pop(0)
            else:
                return False

    if len(match) == 0:
        return True

    return False
```

Test it:

```
import time

millis = float(time.time() * 1000)

string = "[]{}()[][][]"
print "Should be true"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "([()][][{}])"
print "Should be true"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "[(])"
print "Should be false"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "[([])()({})]"
print "Should be true"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "[(,,),(,,[])]"
print "Should be true"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "[(,,,(,,[])]"
print "Should be false"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "]"
print "Should be false"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "["
print "Should be false"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "{[{}][][({})]}"
print "Should be true"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = """
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
"""

print "Should be true"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

string = "[[[((({{{}}})))]]]"
print "Should be true"
print str(pairs_stack(string))

millis = float(time.time() * 1000) - millis
print "Result " + str(millis)
```